# SQL SELECT statement with Cast, LPad and Max

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Are there any issues with this select statement ??

```
    SELECT SUBSTR(FIELD_A,10,3) as MOVID, 
    MAX(LPAD((CAST(SUBSTR(FIELD_A,-3,3) as INT) + 1 ), 3, 0)) as NEXTMOVID
    FROM ...
```

The field is a `VARCHAR2`.

I want to maintain 3 characters(which are numbers) and add 1 and concatenate with another varchar2

1. retrieve a portion of the `FIELD_A`
2. convert is to an integer
3. add 1
4. Left Pad it to 3 characters with 0
5. Grab the `MAX`
6. Later on I concatenate with another field

Wondering if there was a better way to do this ??

Comment: Are you grouping on `FIELD_A`? What is `MAX()` supposed to be for? You're mixing aggregated and non-aggregated uses of `FIELD_A` so that's why I'm asking.

Comment: It's hard to answer "better" without knowing why the field is structured the way it is, and how it's being used.  Without knowing these things, the only suggestion would be to use a separate field to store the integer value.  You can then reference that field to do your other operations.

Comment: If you add some sample records and expected output to your question you are more likely to get the answer you need.  As it stands we lack the context needed to help you.

Comment: yes I am grouping on FIELD_A - FI(ELD_A is a string of many characters

Comment: It might make sense to take the max first on the int value rather than the string but that's probably mostly a matter of preference. Are you sure you even need the `lpad()`?

Comment: I need the LPAD because I am concatenating it with another field to create a unique identifier - so yes I do need the 3 characters - a must

Comment: Ok. You need `lpad` for the range of values from '000' to '098' since you have to "re-pad" the numeric value after incrementing it. But notice that `lpad(1000, 3)` returns '100'. You need to be careful when `FIELD_A` ends in '999'.

Comment: It will be rare when FIELD_A gets to be over 100 - it might happen but certainty not more than 150 ever...

Comment: Scratch my previous comment: you definitely don't need `MAX()` at all. All rows in your group will have the same `FIELD_A` value and so also the last three characters. Your expression looks fine but I don't know Oracle well enough so there could be a clever shortcut.

Comment: I definetly need the MAX otherwise more records would be returned - has to be only 1 - the one with the highest value - thats why the MAX exists - otherwise I would need a subquery with WHERE ROWNUM=1

Comment: @Rus My comment about `MAX()` is based on your previous statement that you're grouping on `FIELD_A`. If you're grouping then you only have one value per group and Oracle knows that. Here's a SQL Server fiddle showing my point:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47d5e/3 (I couldn't get Oracle fiddles to run right now but I tested it locally. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/3)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you need following:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(FIELD_A,10,3) as MOVID, 
       to_char(to_number(SUBSTR(FIELD_A, -3, 3)) + 1), '000') as NEXTMOVID
FROM ...
```

Comment: If you make the pattern `'FM000'` then it won't have a leading space (left for the possibility of a minus sign); which will work better when the OP concatenates the value. Otherwise it would have to be trimmed. But, this isn't doing the `MAX` part.

Comment: @Alex OP says there is grouping on `FIELD_A`. Unless I'm overlooking something in the way Oracle handles expression derived from a grouping column the `MAX()` isn't even necessary.

Comment: I assumed the OP actually meant they were grouping on `SUBSTR(FIELD_A,10,3)`, but it isn't clear at all. Hard to work out what they're really doing (or trying to do).

Comment: When I was writing my answer, I've read comments and thought that `max` isn't necessary. Anyway, it is not so hard to add it.